# XML document for UPS Freight Shipping

Tags: xml, coldfusion, web-services, ups

I was wondering if anyone knew of where I could find an example XML document so that I could get get a FREIGHT LTL shipping quote from the UPS API.  My XML mojo is seriously deficient, and all UPS has provided me is an XSD document.  My client is really hoping that I can get this done sooner rather than later, and I need to send this as an XML post rather than a SOAP request as the site is written in ColdFusion 8 and if I recall correctly, Coldfusion has to have a publicly facing WSDL to create a webservice (I have been doing too much .NET development lately).

Can anyone help out?

**EDIT:**

This needs to support FREIGHT, unless I missed the boat, the download @ RIAForge only supports standard shipping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try the CF UPS package at RIAForge? http://cfups.riaforge.org.

Comment: Ray, I should have known . . . . Thanks I will take a look into it.  Will it handle Freight?

Comment: I explicity need FREIGHT, LTL shipping

Comment: I honestly don't remember -did you download the code and look? :)